# Definition of intersection pairing on an arithmetic surface

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, arakelov-theory, heights

$\def\div{\operatorname{div}} \def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$Let $K$ be a number field, $O_K$ be the ring of integers, and $X \to \Spec(O_K)$ be a regular arithmetic surface. I want to understand how the intersection number of a Hermitian line bundle $(L, \|\cdot\|)$ and an irreducible horizontal Weil divisor $D$, is defined (and how this is related to the height of $D$ with respect to $L$).

It appears that there are two ways to define this.

1. Consider the metrized line bundle $O_X(D)$, equipped with the Arakelov metric for each archimedean place $v$. Take a section $l$ of $L$, and $m$ of $O_X(D)$.

- For intersection number at finite place, one can consider the degree of the "usual" intersection in surface theory $[\div(l)] \cdot [\div(m)]$.
- For intersection number at each infinite place $v$, one can use the Deligne bracket
  $$\langle l, m \rangle_v := \int_X \frac{\partial \overline{\partial}}{\pi i} \log \|l\| \cdot \log \|m\| + \log \|l\| [\div(m)] + \log \|m\|[\div(l)]$$
- One can then define the intersection number overall as
  $$\langle L, D \rangle := [\div(l)] \cdot [\div(m)] - \sum_{v | \infty} \langle l, m \rangle_v$$

2. Treating the horizontal divisor as image of the section $p: \Spec(O_K) \to X$, one can pull $L$ back to $p^*L$, a metrized line bundle on $\Spec(O_K)$. One can then define the intersection as the degree of $p^*L$ on $\Spec(O_K)$. Explicitly, suppose $p^*L$ corresponds to the rank 1 projective $O_K$-module $M$. Suppose $P = p\bigl(\Spec(K)\bigr)$. If $l$ is a section of $L$ that does not meet $D$ on the generic fiber, then
   $$\langle L, D\rangle := \log \# (M / O_K \cdot p^*l) - \sum_{v | \infty} \log \|l(P)\|_v$$

**Questions**

- Are these two definitions equivalent? If not, how are they related?

  - If I am not mistaken, the intersection at finite place already matches up, and we only need to check if intersection numbers match up for each archimedean place.
  - It seems to me that for these two definitions to be equivalent, I would need the integral of log Green's function with respect to curvature form of $(L, \|\cdot\|)$ to vanish, which I suppose is false for general metrics on $L$.
- Is there a standard reference around this?

  - I saw Lang's book on Arakelov geometry, which only considers admissible metrics on line bundles. I would like to allow $L$ to be arbitrary metrized line bundle at least. The only reference I have at the moment is Appendix B of Pineiro-Szpiro-Tucker "Mahler measure for dynamical systems on $\mathbb{P}^1$," but I suppose there must be a more standard reference.

Thank you! (I am very new to Arakelov geometry, so please excuse me if this question isn't framed correctly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at Chapter 4 of Moriwaki's Book "Arakelov Geometry". In particular, your question seems to be answered in Proposition 4.19.

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent reference - I wish I knew this book much earlier! I now understand where I was wrong (in approach 1, I was thinking about admissibility where curvature form is the canonical volume form, but I should have considered admissibility where curvature form is compatible with metric on $L$, then everything would work out)

Comment: A quick follow up question if you don't mind: I am most interested in the case of naive heights (say for $\mathbb{P}^1$), defined using $L^{\infty}$-norm, which is not smooth. This is why I may not be able to work with smooth metrics. In this setting, curvature form can still make sense as a distribution (e.g. Zhang, "Positive line bundle on arithmetic surface" Section 1). Does Corollary 4.11 in Moriwaki's book still hold in that set up? Thanks again!

Comment: One can approximate the non-smooth form by a sequence of smooth forms $\Omega_n$. Applying Corollary 4.11 to the forms $\Omega_n$ of this sequence (and fixing some normalization by $\int\log|s|_n\Omega_n=0$) one obtains a sequence of metrics $|\cdot|_n$, which should converge to a metric having the given non-smooth form as curvature form.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Hi again! Following up on above, do you know of a reference that documents basic results in the case curvature form is a distribution? In other words, a reference that pins down the class of continuous metrics to consider, the suitable generalization of real (1,1)-form for Corollary 4.11 to hold in this set up, existence of Green functions etc. Thank you again!